# jsf: generate another panelGrid

Tags: java, jsf

My code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>

<f:view>
 <html>
  <body>
   <h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="3" border="1" rules="all" title="This is panelGroup demo">
  <f:facet name="header">
  <h:outputText value="Submit Detail"/>
  </f:facet>
   <h:inputText/>
   <h:inputText/>
   <h:inputText/>
   <h:inputText/>
   <h:inputText/>
   <h:inputText/>
   <h:inputText/>
   <h:inputText/>
  <f:facet name="footer">
  <h:panelGroup>
   <h:outputText value="Leave Comment Here :" />
   <h:inputText/>
   <h:outputText value="Submit" />
   <h:commandButton value="SUBMIT" />
  </h:panelGroup>
  </f:facet>
</h:panelGrid> 
  </h:form>
  </body>
 </html>
</f:view>
```

I want to put a commandButton tag. When I click on the button it should  generate another panelgrid with the same number of columns and rows (Each time I click).
what should I add to realize it?

Comment: Do you want to generate it dynamically or statically?

Answer (score 1):

You can put you `panelGrid` inside a `dataTable` and then wire it to a bean that has a list in it. Then, when you press the `commandButton` all you need to do is add an element to the list and the data will render an additional row. Here is some example code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>

<f:view>
 <html>
  <body>
   <h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.myList}" var="myListElement" >
     <h:column>
      <!-- put your panelGrid here!! -->
     </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="Add panelGrid" action="#{myBean.addToMyList}" />
   </h:form>
  </body>
 </html>
</f:view>
```

Each element in the list can then be used to hold information that is to be displayed in the individual `panelGrid`s.

EDIT: Backing bean code.

```
public class MyBean {
    private List<Object> myList;

    public MyBean() {
        myList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }

    public void addToMyList() {
        myList.add(new Object());
    }

    public List<Object> getMyList() {
        return (myList);
    }
}
```

To understand this code I suggest you read about `dataTable` [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnarf.html#bnarz) and [here](http://www.roseindia.net/jsf/dataTable.shtml).

Comment: nooo! don't mix ui:repeat with h:inputText! (or any other editable value holders!) - it is BADLY broken.

Comment: hello
could you show me what do I have to put in the backing bean
i have no idea
help me more please and give me an example if it is possible
 remark :i want a dynamically generate the new panels in my backing bean. thanks for your help